# What is the best Practices to exporting wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

What is the best to exporting API & EndPoint & DataService on WSo2 ?

usually I export the API & EndPoint in same car.file then exporting dataservice in other carbon file

Comment: How are you managing environment-specific information? Like Dev endpoints, Prod  endpoints etc?

Comment: @ycr usually I export the EndPoint & API togather then I export DataService seperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your APIs and the Dataservices depend on each other it may be best to package them together. If not, packaging them together would introduce unnecessary downtime to the other service when updating one service. (Redeploying an API would redeploy the Data services). Also, Carbon Applications are deployed in alphabetical order. So if you have anything that depends on the deployment order you can prefix the carbon application with a number or a letter. For example `1_APIServices.car`, `2_AppDataServies.car`. So they will always be deployed in a certain order on server restart.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the use cases and requirements. If you want to reuse the data service or the API, then you can have them in separate car files and deploy. Otherwise you can have those in a single car file.

Comment: But when the server is restarted in case of seperated DataService the API will not work cuase it's gonna deploy API before DBA sometimes